# Is a 3 LED flashlight brighter than a single LED one? (same LEDs, same power through each LED)

Tags: visible-light, light-emitting-diodes

Say I have one LED in a flashlight, it produces some light.

Now, if I have 3 of those LEDs in the same flashlight, *each* LED receiving the same amount of energy than the single LED was receiving in the model described above (thus producing, individually, the same amount of light), will I get (perceive) more light? Will it be brighter? (considering the 3 LEDs very close to each other, same direction, etc.)

**Quickly said**: does the perceived light "sum up"?

Comment: Ask yourself what brightness is in term of properties of light (number of photons). Understanding this, you should see the answer.

Comment: Does it have to be a flashlight and LEDs ? It is the same answer as having a 100 Watt bulb in a room, or 3 ,100 Watt light bulbs in the same room.

Comment: @annav yes, it can be a light bulb for all I care, and the answer would be the same I think. But what is this answer?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the intensity is proportional to the square of the electric field. So if the three electric fields add up, then the combined intensity will increase not by a factor of 3, but a factor of 9. *However*, in practice the three electric fields are unlikely to be in phase with each other. Further they are also unlikely to point in the same direction. In addition, the possibility also exists that they are all of same magnitude and point at $120^{o}$ in which case they would exactly cancel each other out. So the intensity could actually be anything between 0 to 9 times the individual intensities. This is with regard to the instantaneous intensity, the intensity at a particular instant of time. The intensity which we actually perceive as humans would be the time averaged intensity( The human eye cannot perceive fluctuations more than 20 Hz and visible light frequency is much higher than that.) So we would have to compute the time averaged intensity(square of electric field) over one time period. $$I = \frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}(\vec{E_1(t)} + \vec{E_2(t)} + \vec{E_3(t)})^2dt$$ Because of their dependence on sines and cosines only terms which have squares of these functions would contribute and rest would be zero and so this would work out to be exactly 3 times the intensity of an individual lamp. So it turns out that they do add up - but this cannot have been concluded a priori the math would need to have been worked out.

Comment: The light from the different LEDs isn't coherent and so won't interfere. There will be three times as much light, though how the eye percieves this is anyone's guess.

Comment: Why not E1^2 + E2^2 + E3^2 if the waves don't interfere with each other? Or can't you, as *Will* suggests, consider light as a bunch of photons rather than a wave? (btw, can you really "cancel" some light by emitting the perfect opposite-phased "signal"?)

Comment: "but this cannot have been concluded a priori the math would need to have been worked out." My apriori argument is that energy is additive. 3 one hundred watts each light bulb give the same light as one three hundred watts light bulb.

Comment: @Totor Yes, you can "cancel" some light, though energy must still be conserved. So if you interfere two light waves, the result is some bright spots and some dark spots - you can have perfect destructive interference locally, but not globally.

Comment: @annav so it is *not* additive? I mean, if 3 light bulbs give the same light as one, you get no benefit as having 2 more light bulbs, right?

Comment: the higher wattage (3x) has higher order problems of too much heat concentrated which probaly will age the lamp sooner. 3 with 1/3 of power each is better than one, reducing the probability of remaining in the dark from aging of lamp or accident ( aging follows some probability curve) and other similar benefits .

Comment: @annav please don't get into such practical details (heat and ageing), this is out of question, I'm interested in the theory about light.

Comment: @Kyle yet you can cancel sound (see active noise cancellation headsets), and oppose two mechanical forces so that nothing moves, yet the 2 forces do exist, why couldn't you cancel light?

Comment: have a look at this http://www.gizmag.com/worlds-first-anti-laser-demonstrated/17932/ . A medium is needed, I think for light cancelation to turn to heat.

Comment: @annav: 100W refers to electrical power consumption. a percentage of this gets converted into light. energy would be additive in a time averaged sense if you are looking at the total energy radiated by the lamps. when you want to know the illumination you need to look at the energy density at a particular point in space. this would be additive only if you are considering it as a time averaged value or as an average over a particular region of space. again, this is due to the averaging behaviour of sines and cosines.

Comment: at a particular instant of time, and at a particular point in space the energy need not be additive. it would be the electomagnetic fields which are additive - this is known as the principle of linear superposition for the fields, there is no similar principle for energy.

Comment: @Totor: considering light as photons would be useful when you are looking at how it is emitted or absorbed. when you are how it adds up at a point its the wave aspect which is important. how the light gets absorbed by the eye is as much a matter of biology as physics and i wouldn't be able to comment on that.

Comment: @guru The same wattage bulbs will have the same losses and give the same light and the same energy . Energy is a scalar and is additive.